# Finding a value in {key, value} list in Erlang

Tags: list, erlang, tuples

I'm new to Erlang and maybe I just missed this issue in the tutorial though it is trivial. Let's say, I have a list of {Key, Value} pairs gotten from erlang:fun_info/1. I want to know function arity, the rest of the list is no interest to me. So I write something like:

```
find_value( _, [] ) ->
    nothing;
find_value( Key, [{Key, Value} | _] ) ->
    Value;
find_value( Key, [_ | T] ) ->
    find_value( Key, T).
```

And then do:

```
find_value( arity, erlang:fun_info( F )).
```

I works fine, but should something like find_value be a too common routine to write it? I failed to find its' analogue in BIFs though. So the question is: it there a nice elegant way to get a value for a key from a list of {key, value} tuples?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The module [`proplists`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html) contains [`get_value/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html#get_value-2), which should be what you want.

Answer (score 10):

[`lists:keyfind/3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#keyfind-3) does this. Here I've mapped it into your `find_value/2` interface:

```
find_value(Key, List) ->
    case lists:keyfind(Key, 1, List) of
        {Key, Result} -> Result;
        false -> nothing
    end.
```

[proplists](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html) may be an even better route, though.

Answer (score 4):

Since lists:keyfind/3 was already posted, I'll mention another useful option, using lists comprehensions:

```
hd([ Value || {arity, Value} <- List ]).
```

This means getting all the values such that each element is "Value" and comes from a tuple that matches {arity, Value} inside List. Since a list comprehension returns a list, we get the head of that list.

And using it in a fun:

```
1> List=[{a,1},{b,2},{c,3}].
[{a,1},{b,2},{c,3}]
2> F=fun(What, List) -> hd([ Value || {Key, Value} <- List, Key =:= What]) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.82930912>
3> F(c, List).
3
```

Comment: This looks great, but I have another silly question then: what is '=:='? Why '==' is unwanted here?

Comment: Hi! == can be used to compare numbers, so that 1.0 equals 1, but in other comparisons, you should use the "exact" comparison operator, which is =:= (and would make 1.0 different from 1), see: http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id76768

Comment: This approach is good for lazy Haskell, but in Erlang it will have to traverse entire `List` in any case while `get_value/2` stops when it finds the first match.

Comment: @Ed'ka Yes, but proplists:get_value/2 and lists:keyfind/3 were already suggested when I posted this :)

Answer (score 2):

[proplists:get_value](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html#get_value-2) Is the way to do it if you don't care about the speed

[lists:keyfind](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#keyfind-3) It is the best choice for performance since is a BIF. You can wrapit with a [element/2](http://www.erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.7.4/erts-5.7.4/doc/html/erlang.html#element-2) like this

```
element(2, lists:keyfind(K, 1, L))
```

And you will get the same result of proplists:get_value but faster.

**Source:** http://www.ostinelli.net/erlang-listskeyfind-or-proplistsget_value/

Answer (score 1):

```
find(K, [H|T]) ->
    case H of
        {K, V} -> V;
        _ -> find(K, T)
    end;
find(_, []) -> none.
```